# How to change and get Bar_index of function

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i wonder if it's possible to get the  bar_index value of any function and to change it (aim to offset by 1 )

Ex:(bar_index -1) of request.security(symbol,timeframe.period,close[1],barmerge.gapsoff,barmergelookaheadon)

Answer (score 0):

Why not requesting directly the bar_index - 1 from the request.security function?

```
i = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, bar_index - 1, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)
```